# Excel compare two columns in different sheets return value from third cell

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have two sheets
*SHEET A* contains more than 1500 entries like this

```
    A       B      C 
  Year   Month  Births  
  1880     1     530  
  1880     2     456  
  1880     3     234     
  1890     1     163     
  1890     2     123     
  1890     3     125
```

*Sheet 2* is similar but column C has no entries and there are only a few years and months in random years and months:

```
    A       B      C 
  Year   Month  Births  
  1880     1        
  1890     2               
  1890     3
```

I am trying to find a formula to return the value from *Sheet 1 | column C* to *Sheet 2 | column C* 
if column A and B in *Sheet 1* are the same as in column A and B in *sheet 2*.

I am looking for a formula, no VBA since I can't always use it.
And been unable to adapt anything I find here at stackoverflow.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done really easily with `=SUMIFS()`. Something like the following should do the trick:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C, Sheet1!A:A, Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!B:B, Sheet2!B2)
```

Put that in `Sheet2` Cell `C2` and copy down.

If you are in an excel version before Excel 2007 (when SUMIFS was added) you can use `=SUMPRODUCTS()` do to the same thing, although the format is a bit different. Let me know and I'll type that one out too.

Comment: Brilliant, didn't even think of using SUMIFS :D
Worked perfectly thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with IF and &.

=IF(Sheet1!A1&Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!A1&Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!C1,"")

if(sheet 1 A1 & B1 value is the same as Sheet2 A1 and B1 value, true, false)

Comment: Thank you, this one also works. As soon as I have my reputation up to 15 I will upvote this answer :D